# Remove the object's sibling on click

Tags: javascript, dom

In my program below I am getting the parent node `game 1` and then removing one of the two child nodes, depending on which one is clicked. I currently have two event listeners, with two separate functions for removing one child vs the other. It doesn't feel very dry to me, and I think I could benefit from having someone skilled in JS take a look at this and show me how this could be more easily accomplished.

```
var firstWinner = document.getElementById('game1');

function removefirst() {
    firstWinner.removeChild(firstWinner.childNodes[0]);
}

function removeSecond() {
    firstWinner.removeChild(firstWinner.childNodes[1]);
}

var gameOneNodes = document.getElementById('game1').childNodes;
gameOneNodes[1].addEventListener('click', removefirst, false)
gameOneNodes[0].addEventListener('click', removeSecond, false)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define one click handler that removes all siblings of the clicked element.  That is, remove all children of the parent, except the target of the event itself.

```js
document.getElementById('game1').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // Remove all siblings of the clicked element
    for (var c = this.childNodes.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
        if (this.childNodes[c] != event.target) {
            this.removeChild(this.childNodes[c]);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="game1">
  <button>Alpha</button>
  <button>Bravo</button>
  <button>Charlie</button>
  <button>Delta</button>
</div>
```

You could also iterate this way, but there's an awkward `c--`:

```
for (var c = 0; c < this.childNodes.length; c++) {
    if (this.childNodes[c] != event.target) {
        this.removeChild(this.childNodes[c--]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be useful to use `this` instead of `parent`, since `this`'ll refer to the `game1` element automatically.

Comment: Also, while a little arcane, the for-loop can be replaced with `[].slice.call(this.childNodes).forEach(...)`. Not that it'd be inherently better or anything, it's just an alternative.

Comment: @Flambino I've incorporated your suggestion to use `this` instead of `event.target.parentNode`. Your `slice()` suggestion is too tricky for my taste, though.

Comment: That's fair. I'm not a _fan_ of the `slice` trick either, per se, but it's the simplest way to get a proper array from annoying JS/DOM _array-like_ objects (like `NodeList` here, or the `arguments` obj). Again, not necessary in this case, but I figured I put it in a comment to mention it (no need to put it in the answer)